# Kotlin Gradle issue with app module

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This is my project structure. I use the Gradle Kotlin DSL. The problem is that "My app module is not Gradle-based", but it has the build.gradle.kts file.
I added also the buildSrc to the app module, but it did not help.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHaUv.jpg) as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How does your settings.gradle.kts look like?

It should contain something like this:

include("app")

This tells gradle on the root module (top level) that there is a submodule it needs to build as well.

I also see a file settings.gradle.txt in you project structure. This looks like a mistake to me, you can probably delete it?

Regarding buildSrc: The documentation states:

> In a multi project build, there can only be one buildSrc directory
>   which must be located in the root directory

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:multi_project_and_buildsrc